# Initializers in class swift

Tags: swift, class, initializer

What is the difference in initializing a variable:

```
class Person {

   var name = String()

}
```

instead of:

```
class Person {

   var name : String

    init(name: String) {

      self.name = name    

    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First snippet

  You **can** call

  ```
    let person = Person()
  ```
- Second snippet:

  You **must** call

  ```
    let person = Person(name:"")
  ```

to get an instance with an empty `name` property

---

PS: `""` is easier to write than `String()`